# Verificar duas variáveis booleanas assíncronas e chamar um método se ambas forem atendidas

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-8

Como eu poderia melhorar este método de renderização apenas quando as duas variáveis forem atendidas como **true**, para permitir que o método `renderFilters()` seja chamado:

Essas duas variáveis são preenchidas assincronamente através de 2 métodos de API:

```
//getManager() 
this.isLoadingManager = true;
//getPdiPrganization()
this.isLoadingPdiOrganization = true;

  promiseRender() {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.isLoadingManager && this.isLoadingPdiOrganization) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                this.renderFilters();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    this.renderFilters();
                }, 5000)
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

O problema é que está muito lento... está chamando muito depois das APIs serem chamadas...
Talvez algum recurso do próprio angular, se alguém tiver uma solução melhor...

```
Observable.of(this.isLoadingManager)
Observable.of(this.isLoadingPdiOrganization)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução que melhor atendeu no meu caso foi utilizar a herança do evento "OnChanges":

```
import {  OnChanges,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class PdiActionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
 ...

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.collection && this.isLoadingManager && this.isLoadingPdiOrganization) {
       this.renderFilters();
    } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O melhor seria algo como:

```
combineLatest([getManager(), getPdiPrganization()])
.subscribe(([manager, pdiOrganization])=>{...})
```